# SQL Server TCP/IP times out

Tags: sql-server, tcp, remote-access

I have to connect to a fresh SQL Server Express 2017 on a machine not part of my domain. I have configured

- Mixed Mode Installation with sa with password
- SSMS -> Server -> Properties -> Connections -> Allow remote connections
- SQL Configuration Manager -> Instance "EXPRESS2017" -> TCP/IP: Enable and Active and Port 1438
- Restarted the "SQL Server (EXPRESS2017)" service.

I now tried to access from a remote computer, and got a timeout. I then tried to connect from the local SSMS, which works without special settings, but when under options, forced "Protocol: TCP/IP" is set, with the same credentials as before, I also got a timeout.

So am I right that I can rule out the firewall or problems finding the instance, and everything points towards a configuration issue in TCP/IP protocol, or did I overlook some setting?

EDIT: I have disabled Windows firewall, and no other firewall is installed on the computer. I have restarted the computer. I also found [this article about PortQry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified/) and had a check - locally:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads>PortQry.exe  -n 172.17.41.124 -p UDP -e 1434

Querying target system called:

 172.17.41.124

Attempting to resolve IP address to a name...


IP address resolved to WIN-AECL8CJVS7E.test.local

querying...

UDP port 1434 (ms-sql-m service): NOT LISTENING
```

EDIT: I have run NETSTAT and it seems no port in the 14xx range is open at all, although the SQL Server Browser service is running. I must be missing something there...

Comment: On the machine running SQL Server Express have you added the SQL Server port to be open in the firewall?

Comment: @Richard I have only disabled Windows Firewall, I did not try to open ports.

Comment: @Richard I have run NETSTAT and it seems no port in the 14xx range is open at all. I must be missing something there...

Comment: Is it possible to do other network tasks between the SQL Server and other nearby machines? RDP, ping or filesharing for instance, do they work? If this instance is running virtual, the firewall on the host can also prevent you from logging in. Please also note that if you're working with a named instance, the necessary ports are dynamic and usually not in the 14xx range.

Comment: @Steef But shouldn't the SQL Server browser service (which is running) listen on 1434 and return the available named instances and their assigned dynamic port numbers?

Comment: I see your point, you should then at least see 1434 open... Did you see any connections towards your domain when using netstat? I am trying to see if this is really a SQL configuration problem and not a 'basic networking' thing.

Answer (score 0):

You did not show your connection string, but I suppose you use your instance name here.

In order to connect to SQL Server the network library has to know 2 things: `IP address` and a `port`. Your instance is named and uses non-default port 1438.

So your connection string should use `172.17.41.124,1438` as server name, or, alternatively, you can use instance name like this: `172.17.41.124\EXPRESS2017` but **SQL Server Browser should run**.